# Site is working in port 80 but the same site is not working while changing the port to any other number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

i have to change the port of website for ssl proxy implementation but the site is not working when im trying to listen to any other port than **80** (ex:81,82,90,8443, 9443 etc).

The site works fine in port **80**, other ports getting below error,

**

### Server Error in '/' Application.

**

### No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details:** System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

**Source Error:** 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

**Stack Trace:**

[MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +159
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +256
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +127
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +92

[InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'WRIPMS.Controllers.LoginController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +81
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +280
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__2() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +128
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12650919
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Comment: if the error is with dependency resolver will the site work in 80 port? And more over a site with same files is working in another server, in any port.

Comment: Sorry not exactly. I thought the issue is at IIS configuration

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that one of your controllers has a constructor that accepts a parameter. This is normal for an application with dependency injection. To make it work, you must create a custom IControllerFactory and inject it at application startup using

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new MyControllerFactory());
```

Since your application is working on port 80, I suspect that you have a controller factory (or a dependency of controller factory) that has something hard coded to work with port 80 only.

Comment: Yes dependency injection is there but i didn't hard coded anywhere because its working in my machine's iis in any port and also working in another server too. i doubt that its something related to iis configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Im sorry it was my mistake there was some redundant entries in my web.config like Keys having path to save error log and all. My understanding was it wont make any troubles. It was working in local servers too. Well it got worked when i cleaned web.config redundant entries.

thank you.